# Flash CS6 AS3 Error 1136

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have received the error 1136: incorrect huber of arguments. Expected 1.
On Frame 1 Line 12+13.

I can not find anything wrong with it,  but I am a big noob at AS3, so please be simple with replays.

Here is my code:

```
    stop()

var leftDown:Boolean = false;
var rightDown:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

function gameLoop(event:Event):void{
    moveCharacter();
    keyPressed();     //error here
    keyReleased();   //error here
    gravity();
}
    function gravity()
{
    if (character.y < (stage.stageHeight - character.height)){
        if (testfloor.hitTestPoint (character.x, character.y, true))
        character.y += 5;                          
    }
}

function moveCharacter
(){
    if (leftDown)
    {
        wall.x += 4;
    }
    if (rightDown)
    {
        wall.x -= 4;

    }
}

function keyPressed (event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftDown = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightDown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function  keyReleased (event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftDown = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightDown = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Once again good luck and best of wishes, on finding this troublesome error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error 1136: incorrect number of arguments. **Expected 1**

This one should be obvious. You are calling a function which is defined with one **argument**:

```
function keyPressed (event:KeyboardEvent)
```

You are calling it with out passing any arguments to it:

```
keyPressed();
```

This is why it's complaining! Same goes for ***keyReleased.***

So basically either pass it a **KeyboardEvent** as you defined, or don't call this function at all. Your listener object will take care of it anyway. :)

Comment: I have done that but now I am getting error 1120 on line 39: Access of undefined property event

Comment: If you still really want to pass your own event, you first have to instantiate it. `var e:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('e');` and then pass it as an argument to your function `keyPressed(e);`