# Flash CC error 1136

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to stop this slideshow by pressing spacebar and I keep encountering  **error 1136** with no hope.

```
stop();

gotoAndPlay(15);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressedKey);

function stopSlideshow (e:KeyboardEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop("Home");
}


function pressedKey (event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        stopSlideshow();
}
```

Comment: Rregarding error 1136: incorrect number of arguments.You may take a look here:[Flash CS6 AS3 Error 1136](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26088485/1699210)

Comment: I looked at that earlier but I can't get a good scope on how to apply that to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error 1136 is fired because you have defined the `stopSlideshow()` function with one parameter (an `KeyboardEvent` object) but when you've called it you forgot to pass it an `KeyboardEvent` object as its only argument.

So to avoid that, you can define the `KeyboardEvent` parameter as optional :

```
function stopSlideshow (e:KeyboardEvent = null):void 
{   
    gotoAndStop("Home");
}
```

Also you can use the `KeyboardEvent` object used by your `pressedKey()` function as an argument :

```
function pressedKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        stopSlideshow(event);
    }
}
```

Or you can define a new `KeyboardEvent` object, for example, like this :

```
var keyboard_event:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN);
stopSlideshow(keyboard_event);
```

This will avoid the error but I don't know why you need the `stopSlideshow()`'s `KeyboardEvent` parameter because according to your posted code you can use that function without any parameter ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you so much.